# Copy multiple files/filetypes - from different folders (list of paths) - to a other folder

Tags: batch-file, input, copy, list

Like the title says.

I found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1294140

```
set dSource=C:\tmp\Aufgaben\Tom VPKs
set dTarget=C:\tmp
set fType=*.eps
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%dSource%\%fType%"') do (
    copy /V "%%f" "%dTarget%\" 2>nul
)
```

What i need now, is this:**(    set dSource=C:\tmp\Aufgaben\Tom VPKs)**
but with a list as input.

```
"M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\44329"
"M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\24850"
"M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\26513"
"M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\27256"
"M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\29312"
"M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\30902"
"M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\41285"
"M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\42242"
"M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\42790"
"M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\43665"
"M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\43931"
"M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\44251.2"
```

as such.

a big plus would be a explaination to the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

##### FOR Loops

- a FOR loop gets the list of directories from your text file
- **Note:** prepare your text file **without quotes** around the directories
- another FOR loop finds all the files in the supplied directories
- uses `usebackq` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)) to deal with spaces in filenames (e.g. "Tom VPKs").
- See SO "[How do you loop through each line in a text file using a windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/155932/)"

```
@echo off

set "dTarget=C:\tmp"
set "dSource=C:\Path\to\a text\file.txt"
set "fType=.eps"

rem loop once for each directory in %dSource%
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%D in ("%dSource%") do (
  
  rem loop once for each file in %%D and its subdirectories
  for /F "tokens=* delims= " %%F in ('Dir "%%D" /A:-D /b /s') do (
  
    rem copy only if %%F's extension matches %fType%
    if  "%%~xF" == "%fType%" (
  
      copy /V "%%F" "%dTarget%\"  2>nul
    
    )

  )

)
```

Comment: Okay it works, but a little different than i would like to have it :)
i tested it and it copies all files from the folders in the list.
I would like to get certain filetypes and also from subfolders.

Comment: addressed your comment about subfolders as well as filetypes in the [updated answer](https://superuser.com/a/1768643/)

Answer (score 0):

If **PowerShell** is an option, this code wild combine an array of source paths with an array of extensions and then perform the copy operation for all resulting paths:

```
$Target = 'C:\tmp'
$Source = @('M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\44329'
    'M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\24850'
    'M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\26513'
    'M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\27256'
    'M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\29312'
    'M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\30902'
    'M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\41285'
    'M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\42242'
    'M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\42790'
    'M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\43665'
    'M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\43931'
    'M:\z Grafikdesign\articles\44251.2'
)
$Types = @('.txt', '.log', '.bat')

# Create [String[]] of paths with wildcard basename

$Paths = ForEach ($Type in $Types)
{
    Join-Path $Source ('*' + $Type)
} | Sort

# $Paths

Copy-Item $Paths $Target
```

Comment: How can i use this Script?
Adressbar and type cmd? or rightclick and start terminal?
I also cant paste this code in there, how do i use this :)?

Comment: It's **PowerShell** code. Open the **PowerShell** console either from the Start Menu or `<WinKey>+X,I`.  Then you can paste the code block for testing. You can also save it as a text file with a `.ps1` extension. It's relatively easy to start a **PowerShell** script from a batch file. `Start /min powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass %UserProfile%\CopyScript.ps1`